# Binding a button leads to "Missing argument for parameter in call" error

Tags: swift, button, error-handling, view, binding

I'm trying to create a Binding in two views so I can change something on one side and have it reflected on the other.

I basically have:

- a circle on both views
- a button to change the other view's circle color
- and one to go to the other view

It all works fine if I only have a Binding in the "ColorChange2"
view, but when I add a Binding in "ColorChange1" I get into trouble.

It tells me: Missing argument for parameter 'isOn2'.
But when I add isOn2 into ColorChange1() it wants a binding, but if I do ColorChange1(isOn2: $isOn2) it says it can't find '$isOn2' in scope.

I found one solution suggesting to add .constant(true)) into the preview but since it's a constant, it wont change the view like I wanted since it's a constant.

What can I do to make it work?

Code:

````
struct ColorChange1: View {
    
    @State private var isOn = false
    @Binding var isOn2 : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(isOn ? .green : .red)
                    .frame(width: 100)
                
                Button(action: {
                    isOn2.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Change button view 2")
                        .padding()
                })
                
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    ColorChange2(isOn: $isOn)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Go to view 2")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ColorChange2: View {
    
    @Binding var isOn : Bool
    @State private var isOn2 = false
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(isOn2 ? .green : .red)
                .frame(width: 100)
            
            Button(action: {
                isOn.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Change button view 1")
                    .padding()
            })
            
            Button(action: {
                dismiss.callAsFunction()
            }, label: {
                Text("Go to view 1")
            })
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

struct ColorChange_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
//        ColorChange(isOn2: .constant(true))
        ColorChange1()
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need both `@Binding` value in both screen to connect between screen like that.

`@Binding` means that get the value in `@State` of the first view and make a connection in the second view. In this scenero, when you go back from second view, it was dismissed.

For your problem, make an `ObservableObject` to store value. 1 for present in first view and 1 for second view. Then add it to second view when ever you need to display.

Code will be like this

```swift
class ColorModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOnFirstView = false
    @Published var isOnSecondView = false
    
    func didTapChangeColor(atFirstView: Bool) {
        if atFirstView {
            isOnSecondView = !isOnSecondView
        } else {
            isOnFirstView = !isOnFirstView
        }
    }
}

struct ColorChange2: View {
    // binding model
    @ObservedObject var colorModel : ColorModel
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(colorModel.isOnSecondView ? .green : .red)
                .frame(width: 100)
            
            Button(action: {
                colorModel.didTapChangeColor(atFirstView: false)
            }, label: {
                Text("Change button view 1")
                    .padding()
            })
            
            Button(action: {
                dismiss.callAsFunction()
            }, label: {
                Text("Go to view 1")
            })
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}


struct ColorChange1: View {
    @StateObject private var colorModel = ColorModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(colorModel.isOnFirstView ? .green : .red)
                    .frame(width: 100)
                
                Button(action: {
                    colorModel.didTapChangeColor(atFirstView: true)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Change button view 2")
                        .padding()
                })
                
                NavigationLink(destination: {
                    ColorChange2(colorModel: colorModel)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Go to view 2")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ColorChange_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ColorChange1()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't say it concise enough. The idea was to change the button of the opposite view and not on the same view. So if you press the button you change the color of the circle you can't see. So if you press "Change button view2" you have to press  "go to view2" to see the changes. Right now it only changes the one you can see.

Comment: Dear @b.joe, I've updated my answer. Sorry for getting you wrong